# How to fill out a textbox?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, textbox, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on a program that i need to check for a text file and put the contents of that text file into a `TextBox`. now i've worked with c# windows forms before and i got it working in there, but this is the first time im using UWP. what is the best way to get a string into a textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out some basic UWP sample apps to see how to work with XAML, which is the default user interface markup language. See for example the [hello world sample in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal).

The key for you will be the `x:Name` attribute, which will generate a field for your `TextBox`, which you can then access from the code-behind to set the `Text` property.

An even better solution is to use data-binding, but that requires you to get a bit more familiar with XAML first.

Comment: Yeah thanks dude!  I found out I was in the wrong script .  But thanks for helping me

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding!